# Can't import library in Python - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, matplotlib, pydev

I have been trying for 3 days now with now luck, I really am desperate.

I have installed `NumPy`, along with `matplotlib`. I am trying to include matplotlib into my applications, but it does not work. I am using Eclipse with the PyDev plug-in, but whenever I try to import it, I get an error, even though I have added it to the libraries that it needs to import every time.

I am a beginner with Linux and I don't really know how to do stuff of the top of my head. I would like to know if this is related to `PYTHONPATH` and if so, how can I change it?

Also, when running `whereis matplotlib`, I get `matplotlib: usr/share/matplotlib`.

**EDIT**
Even though I did not manage to solve the problem, nor am I interested any more, I consider this question closed. I have decided to use the free version of PyCharm, as suggested by @FooBarUser.

Comment: @BobbyDigital I think because it is an issue related to [tag:python]

Comment: do you mean you run the code and it gives error or eclipse gives error saying it cant find the library?

Comment: Can you import the module in python by itself (open a terminal, run `python` and then `import matplotlib`)?

Comment: @FooBarUser, I get an error before I try running the code, at the exact line where I have the import statement. (Unresolved import)

Comment: @EvilGenius: when I do that, I get no error when actually import in the console and I type 'import matplotlib', I don't get any sort of error, but I do get an error if I try to use any of its functions afterwards.

Comment: @cgf then it means your python is ok, pydev just didn't understand that you have the modules installed. Recentrly [pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) released a free  version. i personaly think its better than pydev. it worths giving it a try.

Comment: It sounds like pydev isn't using the same python version that is set as default on your system. It's quite likely that you have multiple versions installed in Ubuntu. Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788748/unable-to-import-matplotlib-in-pydev?rq=1)?

Comment: @FooBarUser, I didn't know there is a free PyCharm version. Everything works now without much extra configuration and it is also my personal favourite IDE. Thank you!

Comment: @EvilGenius: yes, I have seen it and tried everything that I could get from it. Not much use. I believe I have "solved" my problem by using PyCharm instead. I know it's a hack, not a fix, but...it works great for me.

Comment: @cgf you are welcome, i know its a pydev issue but i don't know a lot about pydev. since pycharm recently released a free version i guessed you might be interested.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 12.04, modules like these are installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. Adding that to PYTHONPATH may help resolve the issue.In my ~/.bashrc I have

```
 export PYTHONPATH=...
 export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH
 export PYTHONPATH=
```

Edit: if you also have Python 3 installed on your system, numpy might also be in

```
/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/numpy
```

If the latest version of numpy was built to be backwards compatible with both 2.7 and 3.*, the installer might put it in that directory which is meant for packages which can be shared across multiple python version numbers.

Comment: I checked the folder you suggested, but there seems to be nothing in it, so there is no point in trying that. Is there any way that I can move/install the matplotlib library there?